# How to merge it with the second row since they are different widths

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I am building a SSIS package in and need to import one fixed width file where I need to:

- Merge rows into one by linking on an `ID` present in the rows.
- Each row begins with either a 4 or a 6, identifying the rows to be joined.
- Output would only have rows beginning with 4 and ending with row 6's data.
- I also need to know how to format currency where the decimals are implicit.

I was able to bring in the first `row (4)` easily with the `Flat File Connection Manager Editor` with the last column for `CR`,`LF` but stuck on how to merge it with the second row since they are different widths.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Folks here are excited and eager to help you with your question but it's important to help them help you. Consider building a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's important because it shows what you've already tried, your thought process, and what you're hoping to achieve. Also consider using [backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for code sections, it increases readability. For example `41 + 1 = 42` is easier to read than 41 + 1 = 42. Again welcome and good skills moving forward :)

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Before posting a query